# Create np.array from pandas dataframe which has a column holding values of the array's indices and another column holding the value at each index?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like the following:

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 9 |

All the x-values are unique. The x-values also tell the index of the corresponding number y in a numpy array.

I have an np.zeros array that has a shape of (6,).

**How can I efficiently modify the np.zeros array such that it will turn into
np.array([0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 9)?** Notice how at index 2, the value is 4 because when x = 2, y = 4 according to the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
arr = np.zeros(6)
arr[df["x"]] = df["y"]

print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[0. 0. 4. 1. 0. 9.]
```